# Why does my app always crash once I disconnect it from the my Mac?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

Whenever I have my iPod connected to my computer and I build/run from xcode, I have a difficult time making it crash.  However, once I disconnect it and try to run the app by itself, it crashes in no time.  it's much harder to debug with the little info I can get from the organizer console, so this is bothering the hell out of me because I just submitted my app yesterday.  Here's part of the log in the organizer:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000027d8 objc_msgSend + 16
1   TruxMap                         0x0001ef50 0x1000 + 122704
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000652c -[NSObject(NSObject) release] + 24
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000a97e CFRelease + 62
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00009e94 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 140
```

Any idea what may be causing this unusual behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you are releasing an object that has already been released.  Try [turning on zombies](http://www.markj.net/?s=zombie) and debugging in instruments.

For more information about zombies you can see [this link](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=2) and [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html).

Comment: There is just one big problem with this advice: there are no zombies support in iOS!!!

Comment: I dont' think this is true.  Have a look at this link.  http://www.markj.net/?s=zombie  This may be instruments only, but you can get this benefit now in iOS.  I'll update my post appropriately.

Comment: Well, yes and no. You will need to have it running from Instruments, but the description of the problem states that the crash happens once it's disconnected. So iOS itself doesn't have zombies support. It's however worth a try to see if it can be provoked when connected to Instruments.

Comment: Well other than mentioning it's an auto-released object that has been previously released, unless we get more information there's little else help to be had from the description provided.  Thanks for your comments Claus.